# Display BLOB file from database in ColdFusion

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I have a form where users can upload PDFs, which I store in the database as BLOBs. I'm showing a list of all the PDFs uploaded, all of which can be downloaded by a click. I've tried so many different workarounds to get the PDF to download properly but it will say "Failed to load PDF document" in the browser and "The file is damaged and could not be repaired" in Adobe Acrobat. Here is my code:

**Instructors.cfc** (form for uploading file)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="document_filename" name="document_filename" type="hidden">
    <input id="document_title" name="document_title" type="hidden">
    <input id="openFileBrowser" type="button" value="Import Data from Application PDF" onclick="document.getElementById('application_document').click();">
    <input id="application_document" name="application_document" type="file" accept=".pdf" style="display:none">
    <input id="upload_document" type="button" onclick="UploadDocument()" style="width:220px; display: none" value="Upload Instructor Application Form">
</form>
<script>
    function UploadDocument() {
        var fd = new FormData();
        var theFile = document.getElementById("application_document").files[0];
        fd.append('uploadedFile', theFile);
        fd.append('file_name', document.getElementById("document_title").value);
        $.ajax({
            url: "InstructorForms.cfc?method=getApplicationPDFData",
            type: "post",
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false
         });
</script>
```

**InstructorForms.cfc** (inserts PDF blob to database)

```
<cffunction name="getApplicationPDFData" access="remote">    
    <cfset uploadDirectory = "#expandPath('../UPLOADS')#">
    <cfif not directoryExists(uploadDirectory)>
        <cfdirectory action="create" directory="#uploadDirectory#">
    </cfif>
    <cfif IsDefined("uploadedFile")>
        <cffile action="upload" fileField="uploadedFile" destination="#uploadDirectory#" nameConflict="overwrite" accept="application/pdf">
    </cfif>
    <cfif IsDefined("file_name")>
        <cfset filePath = uploadDirectory & "\" & file_name>
        <cfpdfform action="read" source="#filePath#" result="documentStruct" />
        <cfset nameArray = documentStruct.Name.split(",")>
        <cffile action="readbinary" file="#filePath#" variable="binPDF">
        <cfquery name="addPDFToDB" datasource="#request.dsn#">
            INSERT INTO DDMS.UPLOADED_FILES (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, DOCUMENT, DOCUMENT_TYPE)
            VALUES(<cfqueryparam value="#nameArray[1]#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">, 
                   <cfqueryparam value="#ltrim(rtrim(nameArray[2]))#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">, 
                   <cfqueryparam value="#binPDF#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob">,
                   'Instructor Application')
        </cfquery>
        <cffile action="delete" file="#filePath#">
</cffunction>
```

**Instructors.cfc** [again] (downloading PDF from database, where I'm having trouble)

```
<cffunction name="downloadPDF" access="remote" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="uploaded_file_id" required="yes" type="numeric">
    <cfquery name="getInstructorApplication" datasource="#request.dsn#" result="output">
        SELECT DOCUMENT, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM DDMS.UPLOADED_FILES WHERE UPLOADED_FILE_ID = #arguments.uploaded_file_id#
    </cfquery>
    <cfset fileName = getInstructorApplication.LAST_NAME & "_" & getInstructorApplication.FIRST_NAME & "_application.pdf">
    <cfset cfTags = "">
    <cfsavecontent variable="cfTags">
        <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#fileName#">
        <cfcontent variable="#getInstructorApplication.DOCUMENT#" type="application/pdf" reset="yes">
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn cfTags>
</cffunction>
```

The most important section of code is the last/above snippet I included. Even when I navigate to the `downloadPDF` function in the browser, it still won't download the PDF properly and gives the error messages. So cleaning that method up is step #1, and then I can actually retrieve the PDF on the user's page through an AJAX call, which I will also show in case it is helpful:

```
$(".pdfFile").on("click", function() {
    var uploaded_file_id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "CFC/Instructors.cfc?method=downloadPDF",
        data: { "uploaded_file_id": uploaded_file_id },
        success: function(blob, status, xhr) {
            var filename = "";
            var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }
                                
            if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var newBlob = new Blob([blob], {type: "application/pdf"});
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
                                
                if (filename) {
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                        window.location.href = downloadUrl;
                    } else {
                        a.href = downloadUrl;
                        a.download = filename;
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                    }
                } else {
                    window.location.href = downloadUrl;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Sorry for the overwhelming amount of code. But like I said, the most important part is in the `downloadPDF` function, where I utilize `cfcontent` and need to load the binary data properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been stuck on this problem for a while and can't find much documentation.

**UPDATE:**

The PDF returned is of size 62.5 KB, and I've heard that output can be truncated to 64 KB due to a buffer in ColdFusion Admin if BLOB retrieval is disabled. I don't have access to ColdFusion Admin, yet one of my coworkers does, and perhaps he edited a wrong setting when attempting to enable BLOB retrieval globally. I'll check with him.

Comment: There are many reasons to not store documents (PDFs, images, etc) in the database. This is one of them. Was this working already and is now broken after a code update? Server update? JVM update? If this isn't in production yet, I'd suggest moving the documents out of the DB and load them from a non-public folder on the server. Otherwise, use S3 or a similar document service to distribute the files.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno My company prefers to store documents in the DB, due to reasons like keeping relational data among them and to avoid a large overhead on the server's file system. So as of now, I'm stuck with storing a blob to the database. This hasn't been working to this point, and I'm glad you brought up "server update" because I forgot to mention we did enable BLOB retrieval in ColdFusion Administrator, yet still no luck.

Comment: I worked on an application many years ago that stored files in the DB and presented hyperlinks to download a file with one click.  But it did not use a CFC and instead just had a CFM page to push out the files.  It was basically the code you have in your CFSAVECONTENT within your CFC but directly on the CFM page.  It had a security check, then query, and then this:

<cfheader name='Content-Disposition' value='attachment;filename=#ListLast(qryGetLob.SOURCE_PATH, "\/")#'>

<cfcontent type="application/unknown" variable="#qryGetLob.BLOBDATA#">

So wonder if maybe work in a standalone page?

Comment: Yes. Also for the cfc, try getting rid of the cfsavecontent ie don't wrap the cfheader/cfcontent call in anything, just write it to the browser

Comment: Is your DB column of `varbinary(max)` type? The 'usual' problem is seeing output truncated to the 64KB default Blob Buffer setting because BLOB retrieval hasn't been enabled on the datasource, but you say it has, so I'd echo what @SOS said - the `cfheader`+`cfcontent` write direct to the browser, they are not outputting strings for you to wrap and return in the function. As an aside, also worth noting that `reset="yes"` is ignored when using a `variable` or `file` attribute with `cfcontent`, and it looks like the author might benefit from reading up on local/var scoping in CF functions.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments to try to help me; I'll address each one of them. @Snipe656 I tried putting the code on a standalone CFM page but it makes no difference; same errors.

Comment: @SOS I tried to neglect the return of the `cfsavecontent`, but if I do that, then nothing is returned to the AJAX call and no binary data can be used to display the file.

Comment: @SevRoberts I am using type `blob` in the database since I am using Oracle; `varbinary(max)` is for SQL Server. BUT you bring up a very interesting point that the output can be truncated to 64 KB; the original file uploaded was 943 KB and the CFC method is returning a PDF of size 62.5 KB, which is very close to 64 KB, so I'm starting to think that is the issue. I did ask one of my coworkers with access to ColdFusion Admin to enable BLOB retrieval, but he may not have done that on the Dev environment (i.e. Staging or Production) or there are additional settings he missed. I'll ask him tomorrow.

Comment: Yes 62.5KB would be the precise limit in binary bytes. The default BLOB buffer setting value is actually 64000 bytes not 64KB, so 64000/1024 = 62.5 KB. I've only done this with MS SQL and MySQL, not Oracle, so I don't know if there are any unique quirks with the Oracle driver. You could also try increasing the BLOB buffer in CF Admin to eg  1048576 bytes (1MB) to prove that is currently the limiting factor, although it should not be necessary if BLOB is enabled on the datasource. You should also be able to prove your code itself is valid by testing with smaller PDF files.

Comment: @MaxVoisard - You need to remove the savecontent and the return. As Sev mentioned, the data is written directly to the http response so there is nothing for the function to return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a setting in ColdFusion Administrator that was causing the problem. Although BLOB retrieval was enabled *globally* for the Dev environment, it wasn't enabled on my particular *datasource*. Enabling BLOB retrieval in the global settings is only step 1; it won't cover the datasource unless you enable it explicitly.

I did have to tweak my code a little, but not much. I changed the `cfcontent` to use the `file` attribute instead of `variable`, which I populated the `file` attribute with the path used from a `<cffile action="write">`. After having written the file to the server, I create an anchor link for the file via JavaScript and call its `click()` method so the PDF attachment will download. After that, I do another AJAX call in the `done()` method to delete the file, as I don't need to keep that file on the server; it's a temporary thing. Here is my final code:

**Instructors.cfc** (file upload form stays the same)

```
<cfquery name="getInstructorApplications" datasource="#this.dsn#">
    SELECT fm.FILELOB_ID, fm.FILEMETA_ID, fm.TITLE, fm.FILEEXT, fm.FILE_LEN, fm.CREATEDDATE
    FROM DDMS.FILEMETA fm
    JOIN DDMS.FILELOB fl
    ON fm.FILELOB_ID = fl.FILELOB_ID
    WHERE fl.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'Instructor Application'
</cfquery>

<table class="DataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 200px">File Name</th>
            <th>File Extension</th>
            <th>File Size</th>
            <th>Date Uploaded</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <cfloop query="getInstructorApplications">
            <cfoutput>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 200px">
                        <a data-id="#FILELOB_ID#" data-meta-id="#FILEMETA_ID#" data-filename="#TITLE#" class="pdfFile" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer">#TITLE#</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>#FILEEXT#</td>
                    <td>#FILE_LEN#</td>
                    <td>#DATEFORMAT(LEFT(CREATEDDATE, 10))#</td>
                </tr>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfloop>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(".pdfFile").on("click", function() {
        var file_id = $(this).data("id");
        var file_meta_id = $(this).data("meta-id");
        var file_name = $(this).data("filename");
        var now = new Date();
        var ticks = now.getTime();
        <cfoutput>
            var #ToScript(cfcPath, "cfcRoot")#;
        </cfoutput>
        $.ajax({
            url: cfcRoot + "CFC/FileManager.cfc?method=ServeFileDownload&random=" + ticks,
            type: "post",
            data: { "FileID": file_id,
                    "FileMetaID": file_meta_id,
                    "fileName": file_name },
            success: function() {
                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                        a.href = cfcRoot + "UPLOADS/" + file_name;
                        a.download = file_name;
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                      }
         }).done(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: cfcRoot + "CFC/FileManager.cfc?method=DeleteFile&random=" + ticks,
                data: { "fileName": file_name }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**FileManager.cfc** (new file, takes over InstructorForms.cfc)

```
<cffunction name="ServeFileDownload" access="remote" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="FileID" type="numeric" required="no" default=0>
    <cfargument name="FileMetaID" type="numeric" required="no" default=0>
    <cfargument name="fileName" type="string" required="no" default="">
    
    <cfif ARGUMENTS.FileID NEQ 0>
        <cfset local.FileMetaID = GetCurrentMetaIDByFileID(FileID=ARGUMENTS.FileID)>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset local.FileMetaID = ARGUMENTS.FileMetaID>
    </cfif>
    
    <cfif local.FileMetaID NEQ 0>
        <cfset ServeFile( FileMetaID=ARGUMENTS.FileMetaID, ServeType="attachment", filename="#ARGUMENTS.fileName#")>
    <cfelse>
        <cfreturn "">
    </cfif>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="ServeFile" access="public" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="FileMetaID" type="numeric" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="ServeType" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="fileName" type="string" required="no" default="">
    <cfquery name="GetFileMetaData" datasource="#application.DDMS.dsn#">
        SELECT fm.FILEMETA_ID, fm.FILELOB_ID, fl.FILELOB, fm.FILE_ID, fm.TITLE, fm.FILEEXT, fm.MIMETYPE_ID, fm.FILE_LEN
        FROM DDMS.FILEMETA fm
        JOIN DDMS.FILELOB fl
        ON fm.FILELOB_ID = fl.FILELOB_ID
        WHERE fm.FILEMETA_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ARGUMENTS.FileMetaID#">
        AND fm.ISACTIVE = 1
    </cfquery>
    <cfset MIMETypeObj = CreateObject("component","#application.global.cfcpath#.filemanager.mimetype")>
    <cfset local.filename = Len(ARGUMENTS.fileName) ? "#ARGUMENTS.fileName#" : "#GetFileMetaData.TITLE#">
    <cfset local.MIMETYPE = MIMETypeObj.GetMIMETypeByID(MIMETYPEID=GetFileMetaData.MIMETYPE_ID)>
    <cfif ARGUMENTS.ServeType EQ "attachment">
        <cfset local.MIMETYPE = "application/octet-stream">
    </cfif>
    <cfset uploadDirectory = "#expandPath('../UPLOADS')#">
    <cfset filePath = uploadDirectory & "\" & arguments.fileName>
    <cfset RecordDownloadUsage(FILEMETAID=ARGUMENTS.FileMetaID,FILENAME="#local.filename#")>
    <cffile action="write" file="#filePath#" output="#GetFileMetaData.FileLOB#" >
    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="#ARGUMENTS.ServeType#;filename=#local.filename#;" />
    <cfcontent file="#filePath#" type="#local.MIMETYPE#" />
    <cfreturn ToString(uploadDirectory & "/" & arguments.fileName)>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="DeleteFile" access="remote" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="fileName" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfset uploadDirectory = "#expandPath('../UPLOADS')#">
    <cfset filePath = uploadDirectory & "\" & arguments.fileName>
    <cffile action="delete" file="#filePath#">
</cffunction>
```